# Robust importing of shapefile into spatialite database?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, spatialite, import

I am trying to import shapefiles into a spatialite database using spatialite-gui.

I am having problems with the types of the variables since spatialite-gui has no obvious way to handle shapes which use `","` as decimal separator, and mangles my date fields which are in `YYYY/MM/DD` format.

QGIS 1.7.4 imports the same shapefiles without any issues, handling all the conversions transparently, but will not let me save to a Spatialite database.

Is there a more robust way of importing a shapefile into Spatialite?

Comment: Are you willing to use the command line interface?

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy with the conversion QGIS does, just get the new QGIS version 2.0. It will happily save to Spatialite.

Comment: I have tried this feature from QGIS 2.0. it's great to see QGIS improving in this respect

Answer (score 1):

Well since I was doing this for a django project, I Used the ogrinspect command and then the LayerMapping function to import the data:

you can find the documentation here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/layermapping/

It worked like a charm!